# Altering code to return a collection instead of a single value

Tags: c#, .net

I got this code returning a single object but I need to alter it to return a collection instead.

```
public Credit deductibleCredit
{
    get
    {
        if (deductibleCredit == null)
        {
            deductibleCredit = (from c in Credits
                                where c.State.IsADeductible
                                orderby c.EffectiveDate
                                select c).FirstOrDefault();
            if (deductibleCredit != null)
            {
                if (!IsReportable(RecordTypeAlias.Deductible))
                { 
                    deductibleCredit = null;
                }
            }
        }
        return deductibleCredit;
    }
}
```

Comment: So change the return type. What is your question?

Comment: Change return type to something like `ICollection<Credit>` and then remove the `FirstOrDefault` call

Comment: Remove `.FirstOrDefault();`, change return type to your desired collection type. Ex: Could return a `List< >` of whatever type of `deductibleCredit` is and then call `return deductibleCredit.ToList();`

Comment: Change return type From : Credit  To : List<Credit>.  Then replace FirstOfDefault() with ToList().  The curly brackets are not in the correct location so it is hard to edit your posting.

Comment: I would honestly refactor this whole thing and make it a method instead. That would filter the Credits and return me only deductible ones

Comment: btw: if this is a db query, it's bad practice to have a _property_ that is so expensive behind the scenes and even may throw exceptions. This should be a real method and not a property. Properties _should_ be simple and rather pre-calculated and ideally never throw exceptions.

Comment: oh and if this is your real code, `if (deductibleCreadit == null)` will throw a `StackOverflowException` since it recursivly calls the getter again.

Comment: The reasons chosen on the 2 close votes on this are really bad. While I agree it should be closed, how on earth is this question asking for software recs or has typos?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have you change your linq query to return a list not a single object. I don't know the specific collection you'll need, but something along the lines of:

```
//Change credit to List<Credit>
public List<Credit> deductibleCredit
        {
            get
            {
                if (deductibleCredit == null)
                {
                    deductibleCredit = (from c in Credits
                                             where c.State.IsADeductible
                                             orderby c.EffectiveDate
                                             //Change .FirstOrDefault to .ToList()
                                             select c).ToList();
                    if (deductibleCredit != null)
                    {
                        if (!IsReportable(RecordTypeAlias.Deductible))
                        { 
                            deductibleCredit = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return deductibleCredit;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I know the mistake is already in OP's code, but to suggest this **recursive** property as a solution is not good. Note that `if (deductibleCredit == null)` will throw a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 0):

The simple (but not helpful) answer would be to just say:

Change (truncated for brevity):

```
public Credit deductibleCredit
{
    get 
       {
          deductibleCredit = (from c in Credits
                            where c.State.IsADeductible
                            orderby c.EffectiveDate
                            select c).FirstOrDefault();
       }
}
```

To:  (also truncated for brevity):

```
public List<Credit> deductibleCredit
{
    get 
       {
          deductibleCredit = (from c in Credits
                            where c.State.IsADeductible
                            orderby c.EffectiveDate
                            select c).ToList();
       }
}
```

Note: two things changed:

1. the type was changed from `Credit` to `List<Credit>`
2. in the query, .FirstOrDefault() was changed to .ToList()

But that would overlook some other really glaring problems. As others have pointed out, you are going to run into problems because your getter here is

1. Too expensive.  Every single time you reference `deductibleCredit` you are going to execute all this code.
2. If the value ends up being null, it will throw an error.

You would be a lot better off just letting the property by a property:

```
public Credit deductibleCredit { get; set; }
```

But, if, as you say, you actually want a `List<Credit>` then it would be:

```
public List<Credit> deductibleCredits { get; set; }
```

Then, at some future point in your code, when you need to to use `deductibleCredits`, then use your logic:

```
if (deductibleCredits == null || deductibleCredits.Count == 0)
    deductibleCredits = GetDeductibleCredits();
```

And here's `GetDeductibleCredits()`

```
public List<Credit> GetDeductibleCredits()
{
    var deductibleCredits = (from c in Credits
                            where c.State.IsADeductible
                            orderby c.EffectiveDate
                            select c).ToList();
    if (deductibleCredits != null && !IsReportable(RecordTypeAlias.Deductible))
        retrurn null;

    return deductibleCredits;
}
```

(Your nested if-then statement can be merged into a single if-then.)